# Admob React Native google mobile ads not working on real device, Rewarded ads working on Emulator but crashing on real device

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, admob, ads

I am creating a react native app, In my Emulator google mobile ads (Rewarded testing ads) working very well. but when I test the app on my real device(Personal phone) then the rewarded Ads not work, it crashed the app, only banner ads working on real device.

What is the problem, could anyone please reply with a solution?
Thank you in advance

Here below is the code I am using for rewarded ads

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { View, Button, Text, ScrollView, } from 'react-native'
import { RewardedAd, RewardedAdEventType, TestIds } from 'react-native-google-mobile-ads';

const adUnitId = __DEV__ ? TestIds.REWARDED : 'ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917';

const rewarded = RewardedAd.createForAdRequest(adUnitId, {
  requestNonPersonalizedAdsOnly: true,
  keywords: ['fashion', 'clothing'],
});

const Testing = ({ navigation }) =>{
    const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
      const unsubscribeLoaded = rewarded.addAdEventListener(RewardedAdEventType.LOADED, () => {
        setLoaded(true);
        rewarded.show();
      });
      const unsubscribeEarned = rewarded.addAdEventListener(
        RewardedAdEventType.EARNED_REWARD,
        reward => {
          console.log('User earned reward of ', reward);
        },
      );
  
      // Start loading the rewarded ad straight away
      rewarded.load();
  
      // Unsubscribe from events on unmount
      return () => {
        unsubscribeLoaded();
        unsubscribeEarned();
      };
    }, []);
  
    return (
        <ScrollView>
        <View style={{flex:1, justifyContent : 'center',alignItems : 'center'}}>
        <Text> 
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
        Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,
         </Text>
        <Button onPress = {() => navigation.navigate('First')} title='Next Screen'></Button>
           </View>
        </ScrollView>
    )
    
    }
    export default Testing;
```

Please check the image screenshot-
[image] [image] [image] [image]

Comment: Hey, Sir @vinayr any idea on this issue?

Comment: did anyone solve it? I am facing the same error my ad works fine last week but now ad not show in production but on the test ID it works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

react-native-google-mobile-ads maintainer here

You will want to use version 8.1.2 of the module which has a fix I just made to avoid reflective use of the admob SDKs so that proguard doesn't have problems determining what to keep and we don't have problems with obfuscated names post-proguard

https://github.com/invertase/react-native-google-mobile-ads/issues/241#issuecomment-1275530015

Comment: did anyone solve it? I am facing the same error my ad works fine last week but now ad not show in production but on the test ID it works fine

Comment: It sounds like google is no-filling you for some reason. This happens for lots of reasons, to lots of people, all of the time. We have some documentation that explains the most common reasons: https://docs.page/invertase/react-native-google-mobile-ads/common-reasons-for-ads-not-showing

Answer (score 0):

I really don't understand why this is documented so bad!

Here is my working code:

```
 import { InterstitialAd,BannerAd, TestIds,setTestDeviceIDAsync } from '@react-native-admob/admob';

componentDidMount() {
    const ad = InterstitialAd.createAd('ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712', {
          loadOnDismissed: true,
          requestOptions: {
            requestNonPersonalizedAdsOnly: true,
          },
        });
        ad.addEventListener('adLoaded', () => {
         ad.show();
        });
        ad.addEventListener('adDismissed', () => {
    
        });
}
```

Or give this module a try:
npm i react-native-google-mobile-ads

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-google-mobile-ads

Comment: did anyone solve it? I am facing the same error my ad works fine last week but now ad not show in production but on the test ID it works fine